# Create new cocoa touch class missing in Xcode 7

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

In previous versions of Xcode you could do New > File > Cocoa Touch Template to create a subclass of a `UIViewController` with the proper imports, `viewDidLoad()` method and so forth. This seems to be missing from Xcode 7.  When I do New > File, Cocoa Touch Template is missing. I can create a new Cocoa class, but this does not subclass UIViewTemplate. Is there any way to create a view controller class quickly in Xcode 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open Xcode
2. Go to File -> New -> File
3. Under the iOS section, select `Cocoa Touch Class`. Click next
4. For the section that says `Subclass of:` type in `UIViewController`. For the section that says `Class:` type in the name of your subclass.
5. Click next and save the file in the default folder.

If Xcode is not showing `Cocoa Touch Class` and showing `Cocoa Touch` instead, tap on the iOS section again and `Cocoa Touch Class` should appear.

Comment: I've been trying that.  I'm on XCode 7.3.  The problem is when I go to File>New>File>iOS - there is no option for Cocoa Touch Class.  I then try to create a new Cocoa Class subclassing UIViewController.  But the resulting class looks weird.  'import UIKit' is not included, only 'import Cocoa' and the required methods like viewDidLoad() are not automatically added either like in previous versions of XCode

Comment: I've had the same problem; tap on the iOS tab and it should show cocoa touch class

Comment: Thank you!  That was really bugging me.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to fix the problem. If it helped you, could you please accept it? Thanks!